# How do i prepare a JRE of Java 1.8.0 EA for shipping with my Mac OS X app's installer?

Tags: install4j

My goal is to bundle a JRE of JDK 1.8.0 ea (build 120 in this case) with my application files, so that the launcher which is generated by install4j will utilize this jre to run the app.

Now, when i'm trying to set the JRE in the media files options, i can't do the same as in the windows version with a windows JRE. In that case, i was just pointing to the directory the JRE resides in. As i see in the installer build log, it's expected to have a jre.tar.gz in the path that i set manually. So i packed the JRE subdir of the JDK into a jre.tar.gz file. Now, the installer is built without warnings or errors. But when i try to start the installer, it shows me an internal error: "launch path is not accessible".

This is strange because i expected an error to maybe come up when i'm launching the App, but not at this point already.

The opposite comes up when i'm using a JRE v1.7 to set as a bundled JRE in the media file. In this case, the installer starts and the program - of course - doesn't.

How do i have to prepare my Java 8 JRE to ship with my app but not cause the installer to crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

Project->Create a JRE Bundle

in the install4j IDE. It may not work with Java 8 though. We will support Java 8 JRE bundles when it is released.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was searching for the according Menuitem, but there was non. Now i saw in the docs why: http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/jreBundle.html
There's written that bundles are not supported on Mac OS for legal and technical reasons. I guess that i have to find another solution for what i want to do.

Comment: Indeed, the bundle creation wizard for Mac OS X is coming in install4j 6.

Comment: Will install4j 6 also be coming with the release of Java 8?

Comment: It's not directly coupled with the Java 8 release. 5.x will work with Java 8.